# Connect the ios simulator running on mac to Android Studio on PC

Tags: windows, xcode, flutter, android-studio, ios-simulator

I use a pc laptop as my main dev machine for flutter apps (Android studio / Flutter) and I also have a macbook pro
I want to know if is it possible to have the ios simulator running on my macbook and make it available over the local network so I can test (connect) on it my flutter apps directly from the pc
Basically I want to connect the ios simulator to Android Studio on PC like I would connect any device and run my flutter App on it

Comment: I don't this is possible. In order to run an application through the ios simulator you would need Xcode and that is only available on mac.